# Facebook won't confirm my action link

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to get an open graph action link approved. However, it gets rejected without any useful hint about the reason. I think that we are in accordance with the rules outlined in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/opengraph-approval/. (it is about voting on an authors contest, "vote" on "books"). Without the action link, it gets approved quite fast. I suspect that there is a technical reason why it doesn't get approved, and I currently cannot figure out what it could be.
Only once there was an explanation other than the standard text. It read (real URL changed to [our.site]):

> The action link you submitted is not linked to a valid URL specifically we receive this message when clicking on your submitted link: {"redirect":"http://[our.site]/specials/schreibwettbewerb"}

OK. But this interface is supposed to return JSON encoded results, right?
In the logs, on every submission, there is a single test request to this page, without a signed request parameter. This is an error condition, so I return an error.

Does anybody have an idea what I might be doing wrong? The interface is not supposed to be be clicked at, and it returns exactly what it is supposed to return. 
How did you get your facebook action links approved?

Comment: Aren't users brought directly to that URL in some circumstances?

Comment: No. This is the "Graph API URL" and is explicitly an API endpoint. BTW, it works (in sandbox mode). Facebook calls it, parses the result, and changes the action link. But Facebook won't approve it.